# remove seconds from timespan using c#

Tags: c#, timespan

I want to remove the seconds from timespan using c#

My code is here:

```
TimeSpan lateaftertime = new TimeSpan();
lateaftertime =  lateafter - Convert.ToDateTime(intime) ;
```

It returns the value `00:10:00`

But i want the below output :`00:10` only not seconds field `:00`.

Comment: You mean for printing? Or do you actually want to 'round' the timespan?

Comment: yes i want to convert timespan 00:10:00 value to 00:10 only

Comment: Thank u so much i got the result.

Comment: i have an another doubt how can i check whether the date diff is positive or negative..

Comment: @user1065029 If you found some other way remember to add it as answer

Comment: Accept the right answer and open a new question for "how can i check whether the date diff is positive or negative".

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Well you can simply do as

```
string.Format("{0}:{1}", ts.Hours,ts.Minutes) // it would display 2:5
```

**EDIT**

to get it properly formatted use

```
string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", ts.Hours,ts.Minutes) // it should display 02:05
```

Comment: That could be simplified to `string.Format("{0:HH\\:mm}", ts);` which would display "02:05".

Comment: you should use TotalHours instead of Hours so that you don't get a nasty bug when ts is above 1 day.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch, I guess you mean hh because HH is not valid format specifier, according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings. But then the shortcut can't be used when ts is more than 1 day, see my other comment.

Comment: @user829755, my bad.  `HH` is valid for date/time objects, but not timespans.  In date/time objects, capital specifies 24h clocks but timespans only support 24 hour format.

Comment: Better use `TotalHours` instead of `Hours`, to prevent the loss of data when there are more then 24 hours

Answer (score 16):

Note that a `TimeSpan` **does not have a format**. It's stored in some internal representation¹ which does not resemble `00:10:00` at all.

The usual format `hh:mm:ss` is only produced when the TimeSpan is converted into a `String`, either explicitly or implicitly. Thus, the *conversion* is the point where you need to do something. The code example in your question is "too early" -- at this point, the TimeSpan is still of type `TimeSpan`.

To modify the conversion to String, you can either use `String.Format`, as suggested in V4Vendetta's answer, or you can use a [custom format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx) for [TimeSpan.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632.aspx) (available with .NET 4):

```
string formattedTimespan = ts.ToString("hh\\:mm");
```

---

Note that this format string has the following drawbacks:

- If the TimeSpan spans more than 24 hours, it will only display the number of whole hours in the time interval that aren't part of a full day.

  Example: `new TimeSpan(26, 0, 0).ToString("hh\\:mm")` yields `02:00`. This can be fixed by adding the `d` [custom format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings#hSpecifier).
- Custom TimeSpan format specifiers don't support including a sign symbol, so you won't be able to differentiate between negative and positive time intervals.

  Example: `new TimeSpan(-2, 0, 0).ToString("hh\\:mm")` yields `02:00`.

---

¹ `TimeSpan` [is just a thin wrapper](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/timespan.cs,865ef7b89f41b632) around a 64-bit integer containing the number of *ticks* (10,000 ticks = 1 millisecond). Thus, `00:10:00` will be stored as the number `6,000,000,000`.

Comment: This answer is inacurrate actually, i just tested with some TimeSpan retrieved from TimeZoneInfo. I does work if the value to format is positive, but it will not work for negatives values.

Consider:

`TimeZoneInfo myTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");
Console.WriteLine($"({myTimeZone.BaseUtcOffset.ToString()})");

Console.WriteLine(myTimeZone.BaseUtcOffset.ToString("hh\\:mm"));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", myTimeZone.BaseUtcOffset.Hours,myTimeZone.BaseUtcOffset.Minutes));`

Will produce: (-08:00:00), 08:00 and -08:00.

Comment: @GuillaumeZAHRA: You are absolutely right, thanks for the feedback. I have added this caveat (and one other) to my answer.

Answer (score 14):

```
TimeSpan newTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(timeSpan.Hours, timeSpan.Minutes, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there can be more than hours and minutes in a timespan string representation, the most reliable code for removing just the seconds and nothing else would be something like this:

```
var text = TimeSpan.FromDays(100).ToString(); // "100.00:00:00"
var index = text.LastIndexOf(':');
text = text.Substring(0, index); // "100.00:00"
```