# Add hours and minutes from textbox values in ASP.Net (c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, timespan

I have multpile textboxes holding calculated hours and minutes in the format HH:MM.
At the bottom of my page I need a final textbox to total these hours and minutes,should this be done using Timespan?

For clarification (and I know I haven't converted from string in the example below, this is just to show what I need to do)

```
txtTotalTime.Text = txtTimeTaken1.Text + txtTimeTaken2.Text + txtTimeTaken3.Text
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use TimeSpan like this:

```
TimeSpan timeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(txtTimeTaken1.Text) + TimeSpan.Parse(txtTimeTaken2.Text) + TimeSpan.Parse(txtTimeTaken3.Text);
txtTotalTime.Text  = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", timeSpan.Hours, timeSpan.Minutes);
```

Use [TimeSpan.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9(v=vs.110).aspx) to parse your strings into TimeSpans, sum all of them and then format them back to HH:MM string using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8921286/6248956) method.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the TimeSpan-objects for each of these three times you could do something like this:

```
...
    TimeSpan total = new TimeSpan(0);
    total.Add(timeTaken1);
    total.Add(timeTaken2);
    total.Add(timeTaken3);
...
```

Or you could just add up the hours and minutes separately if you do not have the TimeSpan-objects of the three other times but the hours and minutes of them (as you obviously do and you can convert them from String to Integer):

```
...
    TimeSpan total = new TimeSpan(0);
    total.Hours=hoursTimeTaken1+hoursTimeTaken2+hoursTimeTaken3
    total.Minutes=minutesTimeTaken1+minutesTimeTaken2+minutesTimeTaken3
...
```

Answer (score 0):

TimeSpan will add a day if the total hours adds up to more than 24hrs. This should address that issue i.e. 12hr plus 13hr

```
public void AddSpans()
{
  textBox1.Text = "12:31";
  textBox2.Text = "13:40";

  string[] splitArray1 = textBox1.Text.ToString().Split(':');
  string[] splitArray2 = textBox2.Text.ToString().Split(':');
  int hr1, hr2, m1, m2;
  if ((int.TryParse(splitArray1[0], out hr1)) &&
       (int.TryParse(splitArray1[1], out m1)) &&
       (int.TryParse(splitArray2[0], out hr2)) &&
       (int.TryParse(splitArray2[1], out m2)))
  {
    TimeSpan ts1 = new TimeSpan(hr1, m1, 0);
    TimeSpan ts2 = new TimeSpan(hr2, m2, 0);
    TimeSpan ts3 = ts1.Add(ts2);

    int totHrsFromDays = ts3.Days * 24;
    textBox3.Text = (totHrsFromDays + ts3.Hours) + ":" + ts3.Minutes;
  }
  else
  {
    // invalid format HH:MM
  }
```